# How do I make Lightroom's "Done" Button show up?

Tags: lightroom

something not so funny,for me,happened yesterday.
My cat went on my desk and she pressed with her paws different keys,as i was in ligtroom and my 'DONE' button is gone,it's not so big deal but i'm mostly a clicker and i hate to press the enter button everytime.
Does anyone know how how to bring the 'done' button back?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the future, you may want to consider locking your keyboard when you are away from it. Many of my friends with cats do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the cat press T to show/hide toolbar. What you can do is to press it again. The letter is `t` (small letter)

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help, i didn't even noticed the toolbar was missing.

Comment: If it worked feel free to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted :)